# Getting error 404 when post data from local storage

Tags: php, reactjs

I want to retrieve data from local storage and save it to the database. But when I'm trying to post, It gives an error 404. I know the file exist because when I remove this line :

```
formData.append('data',array);
```

my post is work. However, It works on localhost not on live server.

Whats wrong with this code.

Data from localstorage :

```
{
"mylist":"name of list",
"list": {
    "category":[ {
        "name":"Category 1",
        "items":[ {
            "name": "Category item list 1, "amount": "0"
        }
        ]
    }
    ,
    {
        "name":"Category 2",
        "items":[ {
            "name": "Category item list 2, "amount": "0"
        }
        ]
    }
   ]
}
}
```

React js trigger post :

```
function savepackList(){

    const array = localStorage.getItem('list');

    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('type','savelist');
    formData.append('data',array);   //removing this it does not give a 404 error
    axios.post('/request.php',formData)
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response.data);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });return;
}
```

PHP code :

```
if($_POST['type']=='savelist'){

    $obj  = json_decode($_POST['data'],true);
    echo json_encode($obj);

}
```

Comment: Try to print array `const array = localStorage.getItem('list');`, does it prints object?

Comment: No. It prints object when you parse the array in js. Since its not necessary to print as an object. I'm sending string data from local storage as you seen above to php post then convert to decode to use an array in backend. I'm wondering why it works on localhost but not in server.